# Different output levels depending on input voltage / amps

Tags: electrical, voltage

I have some PA speakers that display two different fuse levels on the input label depending on the input voltage:

[image]

Am I right in thinking you multiply the amps by the voltage for the fuses to get the level they would blow at? i.e. 6.3A * 250V = 1575W when the input is 220-240V 2.1A

For the input of 100-120V and 4.5A, the fuse is 10A * 250V = 2500W

The spec for the PA said the peak power output was 2400W, so the fuse for the 100-120V suggests that's right, but does this mean that with a 220 - 240V 2.1A input, the max output is going to be more like 1500W?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. The fuse has to be rated 250V because you might connect it to the wrong voltage and the fuse should be able to stop that.

The alleged power at which they would blow is the nominal voltage applied (220-240 or 100-120V) times the fuse amperage rating.

i.e. 1386-1512W at 220-240V or 1000-1200W at 100-120V

If the input is as rated (2.1 or 4.5A depending on voltage) the fuses won't blow at all. The **output** will be **less than** 450-462W, since those are the power levels at lowest rated input and nominal amperage, and nothing is 100% efficient, especially not speakers/amplifiers. With normal power supplies they will draw less than nominal current at the highest rated voltage. Ballpark of 250-300W might be honest. 2400W is pure organic fertilizer, pre-composting.

The fuses are purely for When Something Goes Wrong and have no direct relationship to the output, other than being considerably more than it. Of course, with a prominent CE mark that means nothing, something going wrong seems quite possible, barring one of the other marks being a local Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory that is not one I recognize from *my* locale. My brief look at the "UKCA" mark seems to indicate that's it's "post-Brexit CE" not an indication of NRTL testing.

Comment: +1 … nutman, "peak" is your new word of the day. It is advertising speak for "I am lying through my teeth about how powerful these speakers are" & is a product of hay + horse you normally shift from the road with a shovel. No honest manufacturer will ever use peak values to bluff you how powerful any amp/speaker rig is. They will use RMS.

Comment: The RMS is supposed to be 1200W, I just mentioned the peak as I thought it related to the fuses. Based on this answer though, the RMS seems way off too? Is there no way it could possibly be more powerful than 300W? Seems strange it would be so far off the mark.

Comment: It *couldn't possibly* be any more than 450W, and that would be Highly Unlikely at 90+% efficiency. 300 is a realistic *guess.*